# how to refresh magento tier price cache after sql insert

Tags: caching, magento, refresh

I've imported new tier prices into the magento database using the sql shown below and when I view the product in the admin, the tiers are correct.  However, on the front-end, the tiers are not displayed under I Save the product in the back-end.

I've deleted the var/cache, rebuilt the Catalog Index, refreshed Inventory Stock Status (?) and even tried doing a bulk Update Attributes on those products, none of which seem to refresh the price cache.  I can't find any value in the product entity tables that relate to tier pricing to tweak.

I see that there is a `Price` object in `Mage_CatalogIndex` which makes me think that it needs refreshing...

I'm using Magento v1.3.2.4 and have a couple of hundred SKUs that I don't want to manually have to Save in the backend!

```
insert ignore into `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (all_groups, customer_group_id, qty, entity_id, `value`) select '0','5','12',entity_id,'10' from `catalog_product_entity` where category_ids = 3;
```

All suggestions welcome.

Thanks,
JD

Comment: To clarify, the tier price appears correctly on the product view.phtml, but not on the category list.phtml...

Comment: And one final note - I tried writing an action that grabbed a collection of `catalog/product` and then walk(`save`)ed the collection, but no dice.  It seems that you can't save a product that simply, it requires a number of attributes to be set.  Too hard. 

Maybe I should have written a Selenium script like alanstorm...

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if trying something like this will help?

```
$productsForCatalogIndexUpdate = array(123,1231); //Add your product ids here
if (count($productsForCatalogIndexUpdate)) {
  Mage::log("About to update the catalog price index on the following products " . join(', ', $productsForCatalogIndexUpdate));
  Mage::getModel('catalogindex/indexer')->plainReindex(
    $productsForCatalogIndexUpdate,
    Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Indexer::REINDEX_TYPE_PRICE
  );
  Mage::getModel("catalogindex/observer")->clearPriceAggregation();
}
```

If I remember correctly it rebuilds the price index tables for the specified prices.