# after importing products into magento they dont show up catalog

Tags: php, import, magento

After i import the products into magento which appears to go smoothly no errors; the products aren't visible in the store. however if i go to any product and save(even without changing anything) it it is instantly available. Why are these products not visible right away...

Running the latest stable build.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is a programming question? Because it sounds like you would be better off asking that in http://superuser.com/

Comment: yeah, this is definitely programming related ... unfortunately :(

Comment: im generating my own csv file from a scraper i wrote... seems to import fine im just not sure why they are not immediately active?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to solve this problem programmatically is to

1. Import the product
2. Examine all the product's attributes via some custom code
3. Save the product
4. Examine all the product's attributes via some custom code
5. Compare the results of #2 and #4
6. Ensure your import process explicitly sets whatever attributes were missing in #2 but present in #4

Here's the snipping I'd use to examine the product attributes.  Run this or something like it in a phtml template, custom controller, etc.

```
var_dump( 
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('sku','SKUGOESHERE')
    ->getFirstItem()
->getData()
);
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fMgjDQRU     thats the output of what you mentioned before top is a visible product the bottom is on that doesnt show up on the frontend... still cant seem to find a reason

Comment: I'd forgotten a method call in there (->getFirstItem()).  Give the edited code a try, that should give you all the attributes.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who is having this problem: I solved it by making sure you set the `websiteid` for the product. If you are using a custom script, remember to add the following:

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from Alan Storm answer, but lower level.

1. Start from an empty database. Dump
   it to an SQL file labelled
   original.sql
2. Create manually one of your
   products.
3. Check it is visible.
4. Dump your database to a file labeled
   manual.sql
5. Overwrite your database by importing
   original.sql
6. Create a csv file to import the
   product you have chosen and import
   it.
7. Dump your database to a file labeled
   automatic.sql
8. Compare manual.sql and automatic.sql
   with each other. You should see
   where the problem relies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have gone into the admin interface and under System>Index Management select all and choose "Reindex" from the drop-down on top right. Execute.

Also, refresh the caching under System>Cache Management and for good measure, delete all the files in var/cache.

If that doesn't fix it, report back for more suggestions.

Comment: Ive already reindexed and deleted all the cache... still no luck.

Comment: This is a sample of what my import looks like 

store website attribute_set type category_ids sku has_options name image small_image thumbnail price cost status tax_class_id is_recurring visibility description short_description product_type_id product_name qty min_qty is_in_stock manage_stock weight

Comment: heres a link that make it a little easier to read i didn't know it would look so gaffed out 

http://pastebin.com/VUkeihNG

Comment: I figured you would have, but have to ask :) Hmm.  I had a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350146/how-to-refresh-magento-tier-price-cache-after-sql-insert) that I never solved... I can't actually read what you've pasted as a sample, perhaps try editing your question and formatting the paste as code.  Check that the Inventory data is correct, maybe try turning on `Display out of stock products` under System>Config>Inventory to verify if it's related to Inventory.

Comment: The other option is to open up phpmyadmin and have a look in the `catalog_product_flat` table and ensure that the values look right. While the live data is read from the EAV model, the flat table might give you some clues as to what's wrong.

Comment: took a look at that table all that shows up there are the products that are enabled

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with dtcuk's solution. Please note:

```
setWebsiteIds(array(
```

Basically even if there is just 1 website id that you want to set, you would still have to pass an array with 1 website id.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. Here the website id is missing. Then it should work.

```
$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setAttributeSetId('9')
        ->setTypeId('simple')
        ->setStatus(1)
        ->setTaxClassId(2)
        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
        ->setVisibility(4)
        ->setSku($sku)
        ->setName($name)
        ->setDescription($description)
        ->setShortDescription($shortDescription)
        ->setPrice($price)
        ->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same thing and after a long troubleshooting I've found, that my CSV was missing one field: "_product_websites" with a value of "base" (same across all the items).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was fixed by switching to English language before doing the import.

Since the import file included some attribute labels in English, the import should be performed in while the same language is selected for the admin interface.