# Magento product import products wont show up in catalog after import

Tags: php, csv, import, magento

I asked a similar question a couple days ago and didn't get any answers that solved my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543992/after-importing-products-into-magento-they-dont-show-up-catalog)

Ive tried everything to get this to work i feel like its something trivial im missing. I have used magento before and never had any problems like this.

Basically all the products import correctly they just dont show up in the catalog unless i go into the product and click save... i dont even need to change anything just hit save.. with almost 2000 products that need to be imported it would be very tedious.

I have everything else set up and im just stuck at this last point and need to get it done asap.

I HAVE tested on 2 pcs with 1.4.0 and 1.4.1.1 all with the same results

LINK TO WHAT CSV LOOKS LIKE http://www.mediafire.com/?01y15k7wv015qwe

Thanks again

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543992/after-importing-products-into-magento-they-dont-show-up-catalog ------- @user398314 - Instead of creating a duplicate question, you should set a bounty for your original question (I guess you'd have to earn 75 points to do that though :( )

Comment: And you may want to use a better subject line to pique people's interest.

Comment: thanks ill try not open a second question next time just wasn't getting any more feed back.... also changed the title hopefully more people will take a look

Comment: Urgent! read this : http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent

Answer (score 1):

Since it could be any number of things, try this:

1. Create a new product in Magento, and confirm that it shows up on the frontend.
2. Import 1 product from your spreadsheet after that.
3. Do a product export and compare the two products.  This should point out to you the differences and help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Run this SQL command.  I had this issue for a long time.

```
INSERT INTO mg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery (attribute_id, entity_id, `value`)
SELECT ga.attribute_id, v.entity_id, v.value
FROM mg_catalog_product_entity_varchar v
INNER JOIN mg_eav_entity_type et ON et.entity_type_code='catalog_product'
INNER JOIN mg_eav_attribute va ON va.entity_type_id=et.entity_type_id AND va.frontend_input='media_image' AND va.attribute_id=v.attribute_id
INNER JOIN mg_eav_attribute ga ON va.entity_type_id=et.entity_type_id AND ga.attribute_code='media_gallery'
LEFT JOIN mg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery g ON g.entity_id=v.entity_id AND g.value=v.value
WHERE v.value<>'no_selection' AND v.value<>'' AND g.value IS NULL;
```

Somebody else made this sql command.  Don't give me credit.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if saving it does resolve it you could use the mass update function and hit edit for all products then save that might also get them updated. Then you wont need to go through each individually.